# Parameterized queries in PHP with phpmyadmin connexion

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to show in a website the products whitch inside in a category. I achived show the products of one category if I put the number of my category manually. However, I don't know how to show the products of a specific category by accessing the data in my database without putting the id of the category manually before my query but by accessing the id of the table of categories that this related to the category_id of my product table.

```
<?php

function muestraProd($DB)
{
    $productos=NULL;
    $categoria_id = 1;

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM producto WHERE categoria_id = ?';
    
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $params = [$categoria_id,];
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $productos = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $productos;
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError : `[$categoria_id,];`, change to `[$categoria_id];`

Comment: @Illya, since PHP 7.2, trailing commas are allowed in arrays so that is not a syntax error.

Comment: Do not confuse PHP MyAdmin (a database administration GUI written in PHP) with MySQL / MariaDB (actual database servers)

Comment: Is this PDO or a specific driver such as `mysqli`? Because you are using questions marks it appears to be the latter. If so, you'll want to call [`$stmt->bind_param('i', $categoria_id)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). If you are using PDO, however, you'll want to switch your placeholder and execute syntax to [`:name`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @ChrisHaas i use PDO

Comment: Can you just pass your category to the function as a parameter? `function muestraProd($DB, $categoria_id){}`, or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, but I don't understand how to do it that way, how could I get the category number before passing it as a parameter in the function?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but a common way is through the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. For instance, if you have a link such as `page.php?category=1` you could say `$category = $_GET['category]` and then pass it on.

Comment: You should always name your functions, methods, variables, constants, etc, in english. That way, someone else with no understanding of spanish can look at your code and understand everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, you adjust your function to accept the category as a parameter to the function, then you can call it and use it anywhere in your script:

```
<?php
function muestraProd($id, $DB)
{
    if(empty($id))
        return null;
    $stmt = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM producto WHERE categoria_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Now that your function accepts the `id` as a parameter, you can use it where ever, as long as you include this function in your script. On form submit:

```
# This will insert the id assuming it is submitted in a form
$prod = muestraProd(($_POST['id'])?? false, $DB);
```

If in a query (as noted in comments) `https://www.emample.com?id=1`:

```
$prod = muestraProd(($_GET['id'])?? false, $DB);
```

Then you can just manually if you wanted to:

```
$prod = muestraProd(1, $DB);
```

These are the most common ways.